# Gradients of a neural network is only 1d

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a neural network with input tf_x with shape `[None, 100]` and output tf_y with shape `[None,2]`. I would like to calculate the gradient of tf_y with respect to tf_x.

Howeverm when I run

```
tf.gradients(tf_y,tf_x)
```

I get a one-dimensional list with shape [None,100]. Why don't I have the derivative of both components? (i.e. shape [None, 2, 100])

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 2, you can use `GradientTape` with `batch_jacobian`. From the [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#batch_jacobian):

```
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  x = tf.constant([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]], dtype=tf.float32)
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
batch_jacobian = g.batch_jacobian(y, x)
```